# Why does the following code not work properly? (Java)

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, do-while

My goal is to receive user input and find out whether or not it's a prime number.

'Been slaving away at this for hours, and it almost works. However, when I enter 2 or 3, I don't get anything. The do-while loop just skips to the next iteration.

The for loop I created doesn't work for 2 or 3, so I created a separate if statement for that. The thing is, it doesn't work. And I've no clue as to why except that it probably doesn't execute.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4a {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); //creates a Scanner that will receive user input
    boolean isPrime = false; //this, in the end, is where the "primeness" of the input is stored
    int num; //the variable which will store the user input
    boolean isOver = false; //is true once the "primeness" of the input has been decided

    do { //executes at least once
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer or 0 to exit:"); //prompts the user for input
        num = scnr.nextInt(); //stores the input

        if (num == 0) { //if the number is zero, the loop terminates; if it's negative, the loop terminates as well
            System.exit(0);
        } else if (num < 0) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        for (int mult = 2; mult <= num/2; mult++) { //divides the user input by 2, tests for if anything remains; increments by one up to the half of the number. If a remain is encountered,
                                                    // isPrime becomes false and isOver true and the for loop is terminated. If not, the for loop will end with isPrime true and isOver false
            if (num % mult == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                isOver = true;
                break;
            } else {
                isPrime = true;
                isOver = true;
            }

        }

        if (num == 2 || num == 3) { //the for test above does not work if the user input is 2 or 3, so a separate if statement tests for that
            isPrime = true;
        }
    } while (!isOver); //if isOver is true, the while loop ends



        if (isPrime == true) { //prints the appropriate answer
            System.out.println(num + " is prime.");
        } else {
            System.out.println(num + " isn't prime.");
        }
    }
}
```

I usually try to solve these problems myself, but I have, again, been slaving away at this for literally 4 hours and I still have another, similar program to write and a calculus quiz to prepare for tomorrow, in which I know exactly jack shit. I'm really desperate.

**TL;DR:** The program doesn't work properly when I input 2 or 3; probably because the if statement doesn't run. Beyond that, I know nothing.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This is an excellent chance for you to learn how to debug code. Also, your poor time management is not a reason to offload your problem on a bunch of internet strangers.

Comment: Put `isOver = true;` in the `if` block.

Comment: /me pulls out calculator and checks value of 2 % 2

Comment: @rmlan "This is an excellent chance for you to learn how to debug code." I agree. That's why I stuck to it for four hours. But I'd rather skip one chance than get an F. "Also, your poor time management is not a reason to offload your problem on a bunch of internet strangers." That is your personal opinion. Please state so and stop confusing it for a fact.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that this statement was my personal opinion. I was to understand that everything I say is fact. This was a missed opportunity for you to learn how to [fish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime), so to speak. Hopefully you learned at least something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `boolean isPrime = false;` to `boolean isPrime = true;` and remove the whole `else`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Lab4a {
public static void main (String [] args) {
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in); //creates a Scanner that will receive user input
boolean isPrime = true; //this, in the end, is where the "primeness" of the input is stored
int num; //the variable which will store the user input
boolean isOver = false; //is true once the "primeness" of the input has been decided

do { //executes at least once
    System.out.println("Enter a positive integer or 0 to exit:"); //prompts the user for input
    num = scnr.nextInt(); //stores the input

    if (num == 0) { //if the number is zero, the loop terminates; if it's negative, the loop terminates as well
        System.exit(0);
    } else if (num < 0) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer.");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    for (int mult = 2; mult <= num/2; mult++) { //divides the user input by 2, tests for if anything remains; increments by one up to the half of the number. If a remain is encountered,
                                                // isPrime becomes false and isOver true and the for loop is terminated. If not, the for loop will end with isPrime true and isOver false
        if (num % mult == 0) {
            isPrime = false;
            isOver = true;
            break;
        }
    }
} while (!isOver); //if isOver is true, the while loop ends
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `isOver = true;` where you check if num is 2 or 3. Because the `do while` loop would never end.
Or you can end the `do while` loop, before the `for` loop starts.

Answer (score -1):

Problem in setting limits for your `for` loop `for (int mult = 2; mult <= num/2; mult++)`.

When the input is 2 `num/2` or 3, `num/2` returns 1, and condition to run viz. `mult<=2` fails.

Comment: Any number % 1 == 0, so all numbers would be prime.